# can't scrape images from a webpage using the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

When I check on this [site](https://lexica.art/), I see a lot of images. I wish to scrape images from that site using the requests module.

This is my failed attempt:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start_url = 'https://lexica.art/'
link = 'https://lexica.art/api/trpc/prompts.infinitePrompts'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'referer': 'https://lexica.art/',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

params = {
    'batch': '1',
    'input': '{"0":{"json":{"text":"","searchMode":"images","showLikes":"false","cursor":"50"}}}'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link,params=params)
    print(res.status_code)
    print(res.json())
```

Output I'm getting:

```
403

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: That site is protected by Cloudflare hence the HTTP 403 (Forbidden) response. The freely available cloudscraper module may help you to overcome this

Comment: The 403 response code indicates that you have an authorization error.

Answer (score 1):

They actually offer an API:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get( 'https://lexica.art/api/v1/search?q=apples')
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['images'])
print(df)
```

Result:

```
id  gallery src srcSmall    prompt  width   height  seed    grid    model   promptid    nsfw
0   0482ee68-0368-4eca-8846-5930db866b33    https://lexica.art?q=0482ee68-0368-4eca-8846-5930db866b33   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/0482ee68-0368-4eca-8846-5930db866b33  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/0482ee68-0368-4eca-8846-5930db866b33  cute chubby blue fruits icons for mobile game ui    512 512 1413536227  False   stable-diffusion    d9868972-dad8-477d-8e5a-4a0ae1e9b72b    False
1   0f19f591-1717-4fa8-b4a0-25958d163f66    https://lexica.art?q=0f19f591-1717-4fa8-b4a0-25958d163f66   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/0f19f591-1717-4fa8-b4a0-25958d163f66  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/0f19f591-1717-4fa8-b4a0-25958d163f66  !!bomb!!, nuke, bomb design, cherry, made of cherries   512 512 2887885166  False   stable-diffusion    d043266e-132b-4b18-be7a-099215310453    False
2   1085f1db-df23-4962-a459-730dd1e2a658    https://lexica.art?q=1085f1db-df23-4962-a459-730dd1e2a658   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/1085f1db-df23-4962-a459-730dd1e2a658  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/1085f1db-df23-4962-a459-730dd1e2a658  not an apple    1024    1024    741458261   False   stable-diffusion    47e06771-2585-4b9c-8abd-c2cbd5728a29    False
3   11f2a286-9ef4-4884-b442-a495c0b31432    https://lexica.art?q=11f2a286-9ef4-4884-b442-a495c0b31432   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/11f2a286-9ef4-4884-b442-a495c0b31432  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/11f2a286-9ef4-4884-b442-a495c0b31432  7 apples inside a brown braided basket  512 512 309592135   False   stable-diffusion    53a41b62-c8fb-4098-9dab-c58a68d57302    False
4   16cf1767-4fe3-4ab1-ab9d-24c193a09ccf    https://lexica.art?q=16cf1767-4fe3-4ab1-ab9d-24c193a09ccf   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/16cf1767-4fe3-4ab1-ab9d-24c193a09ccf  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/16cf1767-4fe3-4ab1-ab9d-24c193a09ccf  not an apple    1024    1024    741458261   False   stable-diffusion    47e06771-2585-4b9c-8abd-c2cbd5728a29    False
5   18bb20b7-f1dd-4014-a4e4-c698499d01cd    https://lexica.art?q=18bb20b7-f1dd-4014-a4e4-c698499d01cd   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/18bb20b7-f1dd-4014-a4e4-c698499d01cd  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/18bb20b7-f1dd-4014-a4e4-c698499d01cd  semi reallistic gouache gesture painting, by yoshitaka amano, by ruan jia, by Conrad roset, by dofus online artists, detailed anime 3d render watermelon monster, watermelon terrible monster, antrophomorfic watermelon, portrait, cgsociety, artstation, rococo mechanical, Digital reality, sf5 ink style, dieselpunk atmosphere, gesture drawn  512 704 2551230084  False   stable-diffusion    22712be3-7fa9-4d95-aec2-dd36323025a5    False
6   1a646e6f-5c33-4794-9d07-9dc2c45cc42c    https://lexica.art?q=1a646e6f-5c33-4794-9d07-9dc2c45cc42c   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/1a646e6f-5c33-4794-9d07-9dc2c45cc42c  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/1a646e6f-5c33-4794-9d07-9dc2c45cc42c  insanely fine detail, still life classical academical oil paintintg, a fragment with a close - up apple. flemish baroque, dutch, netherlands.   1536    1536    1297713546  True    stable-diffusion    13e89043-0756-4082-9eee-ad04abb89747    False
7   20270ecc-3f9d-4561-a97d-e29118c574e0    https://lexica.art?q=20270ecc-3f9d-4561-a97d-e29118c574e0   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/20270ecc-3f9d-4561-a97d-e29118c574e0  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/20270ecc-3f9d-4561-a97d-e29118c574e0  apple   576 1024    895444468   False   stable-diffusion    3a669200-a02d-4432-a12d-07309e9b9a3e    False
8   2858f7bb-6931-4a37-b818-6d4a743c958f    https://lexica.art?q=2858f7bb-6931-4a37-b818-6d4a743c958f   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/2858f7bb-6931-4a37-b818-6d4a743c958f  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/2858f7bb-6931-4a37-b818-6d4a743c958f  artwork of a guava in the style of vladimir kush    1536    1536    2624678908  True    stable-diffusion    261f4447-ddd8-4c0b-ae8b-83df8a538957    False
9   369b2c1b-386d-4813-b646-280ae9d9e51a    https://lexica.art?q=369b2c1b-386d-4813-b646-280ae9d9e51a   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/369b2c1b-386d-4813-b646-280ae9d9e51a  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/369b2c1b-386d-4813-b646-280ae9d9e51a  Beautiful naturist women stand on the side of a lonely apple tree facing the camera holds apple in hand, classical painting, symmetrical, realism, golden hour  1024    832 210477432   False   stable-diffusion    283a7548-d47c-48ef-b703-0297819f9a6b    False
10  3773045f-d32e-4d55-82a1-290db19f6058    https://lexica.art?q=3773045f-d32e-4d55-82a1-290db19f6058   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/3773045f-d32e-4d55-82a1-290db19f6058  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/3773045f-d32e-4d55-82a1-290db19f6058  beautiful aesthetic inspirational digital painting of a close - up cherry, by greg rutkowski, trending on artstation, volumetric light. 1536    1536    2997455144  True    stable-diffusion    9fe37972-91a1-4e43-a52d-dfb40f5e0d55    False
11  4555888b-637d-4475-b1f4-93467acf2955    https://lexica.art?q=4555888b-637d-4475-b1f4-93467acf2955   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/4555888b-637d-4475-b1f4-93467acf2955  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/4555888b-637d-4475-b1f4-93467acf2955  heaven fantasy painting, big pearly gate in heaven, apples, fruit, 8 k, trending on art station, digital art, puffy clouds, godly, godrays  1024    512 556361121   False   stable-diffusion    00bf7214-9e87-4294-bb02-0d376e8acda0    False
12  456731a2-1459-46b5-8537-8deb273ecaba    https://lexica.art?q=456731a2-1459-46b5-8537-8deb273ecaba   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/456731a2-1459-46b5-8537-8deb273ecaba  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/456731a2-1459-46b5-8537-8deb273ecaba  apple cores in different art styles 512 512 616795706   False   stable-diffusion    44f9707d-f68e-4ead-a1d1-0e71dc239011    False
13  47ba538e-767e-420c-bc11-08561b986323    https://lexica.art?q=47ba538e-767e-420c-bc11-08561b986323   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/47ba538e-767e-420c-bc11-08561b986323  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/47ba538e-767e-420c-bc11-08561b986323  A beautiful naturist woman stands on the side of a lonely apple tree facing the camera holds apple in hand, classical painting, symmetrical, realism, golden hour   1024    832 2183080406  False   stable-diffusion    b59d5525-d0db-4881-bf54-3b1fbaf776a1    False
14  484e49c6-1259-40fd-8c64-a1a8a0a46b6f    https://lexica.art?q=484e49c6-1259-40fd-8c64-a1a8a0a46b6f   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/484e49c6-1259-40fd-8c64-a1a8a0a46b6f  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/484e49c6-1259-40fd-8c64-a1a8a0a46b6f  a photo of an apple 512 512 2529659975  False   stable-diffusion    f5c96cff-5b29-4bc4-a1dc-996c47e91a7c    False
15  49c82f05-c4de-4ea5-a6ec-afc32d7dacaf    https://lexica.art?q=49c82f05-c4de-4ea5-a6ec-afc32d7dacaf   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/49c82f05-c4de-4ea5-a6ec-afc32d7dacaf  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/49c82f05-c4de-4ea5-a6ec-afc32d7dacaf  a closeup portrait of a woman wearing a dress made of tangled twisted knotted iridescent ribbon, picking pomegranates from a tree in an orchard, foggy, moody, photograph, by vincent desiderio, canon eos c 3 0 0, ƒ 1. 8, 3 5 mm, 8 k, medium - format print  704 704 2563006189  False   stable-diffusion    3606134c-e832-4090-8306-25c5738d33b3    False
16  5164671f-8a50-4c2f-9ba3-1c5b8862efc3    https://lexica.art?q=5164671f-8a50-4c2f-9ba3-1c5b8862efc3   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/5164671f-8a50-4c2f-9ba3-1c5b8862efc3  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/5164671f-8a50-4c2f-9ba3-1c5b8862efc3  Psychedelic portrait of a Granny Smith apple with google eyes floating in space wearing a top hat , volumetric lighting, artstation, digital painting, very high detail, hyperrealistic, vivid color    1024    768 737376707   False   stable-diffusion    de4d1b46-1b05-43ac-9e06-9f0e0e8c4e8d    False
17  5661f867-cd24-4101-b0c6-6a2e55cd8be4    https://lexica.art?q=5661f867-cd24-4101-b0c6-6a2e55cd8be4   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/5661f867-cd24-4101-b0c6-6a2e55cd8be4  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/5661f867-cd24-4101-b0c6-6a2e55cd8be4  a closeup portrait of a woman wearing a copper bodysuit, picking apples from a tree, foggy, moody, photograph, by vincent desiderio, canon eos c 3 0 0, ƒ 1. 8, 3 5 mm, 8 k, medium - format print  704 704 972944262   False   stable-diffusion    a49316da-bd58-4cf1-af64-3530ed3a590c    True
18  5a88b216-8e06-480d-8778-820d8d9a3fb8    https://lexica.art?q=5a88b216-8e06-480d-8778-820d8d9a3fb8   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/5a88b216-8e06-480d-8778-820d8d9a3fb8  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/5a88b216-8e06-480d-8778-820d8d9a3fb8  a green apple on a red cube, photoreal, detailed, unreal engine 5, 8 k  512 512 2572329254  False   stable-diffusion    f8067a9c-330d-4641-974e-610cbc7b96c8    False
19  5b78d3b9-2e3a-48ec-978d-fc8055123f41    https://lexica.art?q=5b78d3b9-2e3a-48ec-978d-fc8055123f41   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/5b78d3b9-2e3a-48ec-978d-fc8055123f41  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/5b78d3b9-2e3a-48ec-978d-fc8055123f41  an apple doing CrossFit, super detailed, hd image   512 512 3427155591  False   stable-diffusion    ac80fdbd-1e32-4815-9cab-7bd4823999fc    False
20  60faddc6-1b6d-47a7-85bd-8c2347ae2c39    https://lexica.art?q=60faddc6-1b6d-47a7-85bd-8c2347ae2c39   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/60faddc6-1b6d-47a7-85bd-8c2347ae2c39  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/60faddc6-1b6d-47a7-85bd-8c2347ae2c39  photogenic apple fruit, dark lights, cinematic, sharp focus, realistic, in sunset   512 512 13646997    False   stable-diffusion    8dc21b03-327a-447c-b119-76bf980329d2    False
21  67cff8c3-a846-4c17-9378-0356cb76fa16    https://lexica.art?q=67cff8c3-a846-4c17-9378-0356cb76fa16   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/67cff8c3-a846-4c17-9378-0356cb76fa16  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/67cff8c3-a846-4c17-9378-0356cb76fa16  galaxy apple    512 512 2623129452  False   stable-diffusion    77ecab61-3eff-4c38-bd19-55c3a030055a    False
22  6ca4908d-7a6c-468d-aa22-dbcf6e7c20b1    https://lexica.art?q=6ca4908d-7a6c-468d-aa22-dbcf6e7c20b1   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/6ca4908d-7a6c-468d-aa22-dbcf6e7c20b1  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/6ca4908d-7a6c-468d-aa22-dbcf6e7c20b1  portrait smiling hot chloe moretz as gardener in apple orchard, full length shot, shining, 8k highly detailed, sharp focus, illustration, art by artgerm, mucha, bouguereau 1536    2112    1606479462  True    stable-diffusion    0494f4f9-f459-405a-ac32-3815bc2cbc4c    False
23  6ce9e21a-962d-47be-aa9f-dc5c259c486b    https://lexica.art?q=6ce9e21a-962d-47be-aa9f-dc5c259c486b   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/6ce9e21a-962d-47be-aa9f-dc5c259c486b  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/6ce9e21a-962d-47be-aa9f-dc5c259c486b  pacman on speed eating a cherry 512 512 3759614023  False   stable-diffusion    2919a07b-43c3-4282-819b-4b05a114580b    False
24  6d09affc-1410-4761-8701-ec781ad6b8c3    https://lexica.art?q=6d09affc-1410-4761-8701-ec781ad6b8c3   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/6d09affc-1410-4761-8701-ec781ad6b8c3  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/6d09affc-1410-4761-8701-ec781ad6b8c3  painting portrait of a beautiful girl with an apple in her hand, intricate, elegant, digital painting, smooth, sharp focus, shiny gold, realistic gold, realistic metal, by William-Adolphe Bouguereau and Gustav Klimt,    576 1024    3507747382  False   stable-diffusion    7687c392-05bd-44bc-a4ae-ddbf33dec90e    False
25  707af560-5ea0-49f4-ae7c-b4dd022a3fa0    https://lexica.art?q=707af560-5ea0-49f4-ae7c-b4dd022a3fa0   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/707af560-5ea0-49f4-ae7c-b4dd022a3fa0  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/707af560-5ea0-49f4-ae7c-b4dd022a3fa0  attack of the killer's tomatoes. cyberpunk style    512 512 2055904510  False   stable-diffusion    926d4e45-e3ce-48a8-bdf1-4adfeaf16d91    True
26  79a4d97b-904e-4477-97c2-bf1427eff6f5    https://lexica.art?q=79a4d97b-904e-4477-97c2-bf1427eff6f5   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/79a4d97b-904e-4477-97c2-bf1427eff6f5  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/79a4d97b-904e-4477-97c2-bf1427eff6f5  an evil apple, menacing piece of fruit  1536    1536    2173688452  True    stable-diffusion    aa50a2e9-d4c6-4aba-82cb-117be680843f    False
27  7d351afb-d7b1-41ee-948d-0b65c2e12470    https://lexica.art?q=7d351afb-d7b1-41ee-948d-0b65c2e12470   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/7d351afb-d7b1-41ee-948d-0b65c2e12470  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/7d351afb-d7b1-41ee-948d-0b65c2e12470  exactly three apples    1536    1536    1834310726  True    stable-diffusion    d9f5d8d5-8dcd-4979-88c4-3f10fb9e09be    False
28  8d38955c-13ce-405b-b815-fda5a1326f12    https://lexica.art?q=8d38955c-13ce-405b-b815-fda5a1326f12   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/8d38955c-13ce-405b-b815-fda5a1326f12  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/8d38955c-13ce-405b-b815-fda5a1326f12  insanely fine detail, still life classical academical oil paintintg, a fragment with a close - up apple. flemish baroque, dutch, netherlands.   1536    1536    789958954   True    stable-diffusion    62b312c4-b752-40a7-abe5-79e9611683e0    False
29  91fa7c4c-0f1b-4e2e-93a7-fcf251ad2a17    https://lexica.art?q=91fa7c4c-0f1b-4e2e-93a7-fcf251ad2a17   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/91fa7c4c-0f1b-4e2e-93a7-fcf251ad2a17  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/91fa7c4c-0f1b-4e2e-93a7-fcf251ad2a17  apple cores in different art styles 512 512 616795706   False   stable-diffusion    44f9707d-f68e-4ead-a1d1-0e71dc239011    False
30  937274e9-1a90-4ddd-9cc4-49f92b9d1e87    https://lexica.art?q=937274e9-1a90-4ddd-9cc4-49f92b9d1e87   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/937274e9-1a90-4ddd-9cc4-49f92b9d1e87  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/937274e9-1a90-4ddd-9cc4-49f92b9d1e87  an apple on a table 2048    2048    1444513431  True    stable-diffusion    f1cc3eae-9824-4fba-8df6-296adbf6e074    False
31  955c315b-2b7a-4847-8a3e-f0e13b41864b    https://lexica.art?q=955c315b-2b7a-4847-8a3e-f0e13b41864b   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/955c315b-2b7a-4847-8a3e-f0e13b41864b  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/955c315b-2b7a-4847-8a3e-f0e13b41864b  apple   512 512 458991934   False   stable-diffusion    a64f1097-d9dd-4b63-8c5c-58b6cd5ab818    False
32  96d1d06b-92a9-42ac-9afb-786f36b2366b    https://lexica.art?q=96d1d06b-92a9-42ac-9afb-786f36b2366b   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/96d1d06b-92a9-42ac-9afb-786f36b2366b  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/96d1d06b-92a9-42ac-9afb-786f36b2366b  a post - picture of a new delicious fruit vibrant color scheme, highly detailed, in the style of romanticism, cinematic, artstation, moebius, greg rutkowski    512 704 3662723596  False   stable-diffusion    e51731a6-49c1-44ec-9a13-dbd0fa4e7044    False
33  97720e5e-eba2-48d1-b1d5-1df3e12e2044    https://lexica.art?q=97720e5e-eba2-48d1-b1d5-1df3e12e2044   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/97720e5e-eba2-48d1-b1d5-1df3e12e2044  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/97720e5e-eba2-48d1-b1d5-1df3e12e2044  a painting of an apple marc simonetti, yoshitaka amano, ruan jia, rossdraws,    1536    1536    2148704357  True    stable-diffusion    4cef8bc6-7c86-4c92-8060-8a469c75b9ef    False
34  9b98b285-97a1-43e9-9e81-fd994c3a59e2    https://lexica.art?q=9b98b285-97a1-43e9-9e81-fd994c3a59e2   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/9b98b285-97a1-43e9-9e81-fd994c3a59e2  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/9b98b285-97a1-43e9-9e81-fd994c3a59e2  real small apples arranged into bitcoin logo, real photo, top down view 1536    1536    1804574273  True    stable-diffusion    f59ff2b8-7311-4f01-9f55-2c45e6560ec4    False
35  a3c92eb6-b394-400f-9757-42dff9b6d139    https://lexica.art?q=a3c92eb6-b394-400f-9757-42dff9b6d139   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/a3c92eb6-b394-400f-9757-42dff9b6d139  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/a3c92eb6-b394-400f-9757-42dff9b6d139  portrait chloe moretz as gardener eating apple in apple orchard, full length shot, shining, 8k highly detailed, sharp focus, illustration, art by artgerm, mucha, bouguereau    1536    2112    2853497311  True    stable-diffusion    c3e077a0-9e48-4d34-bc53-3256e2365ed7    False
36  a47b1834-e06d-4631-b0a9-c59f786e03ef    https://lexica.art?q=a47b1834-e06d-4631-b0a9-c59f786e03ef   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/a47b1834-e06d-4631-b0a9-c59f786e03ef  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/a47b1834-e06d-4631-b0a9-c59f786e03ef  Psychedelic portrait of a Granny Smith apple with google eyes floating in space, volumetric lighting, artstation, digital painting, very high detail, hyperrealistic, vivid color   1024    768 1206984812  False   stable-diffusion    b691fea9-a1a0-4295-82e2-dcb3c680c9cc    False
37  a5aee1b3-154f-4ea9-857d-749ee80dec62    https://lexica.art?q=a5aee1b3-154f-4ea9-857d-749ee80dec62   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/a5aee1b3-154f-4ea9-857d-749ee80dec62  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/a5aee1b3-154f-4ea9-857d-749ee80dec62  beautiful aesthetic inspirational digital oil painting of a close - up apple, by greg rutkowski, ultra detailed, fine details, trending on artstation, volumetric light.    1536    1536    735893445   True    stable-diffusion    08b31a52-7ef4-4dff-b597-6f93c642ec0e    False
38  aaefeb5f-b21e-4d0b-a0f7-c3becdedaefc    https://lexica.art?q=aaefeb5f-b21e-4d0b-a0f7-c3becdedaefc   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/aaefeb5f-b21e-4d0b-a0f7-c3becdedaefc  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/aaefeb5f-b21e-4d0b-a0f7-c3becdedaefc  delicate fishscale shimmering apple fruit pomegranate   512 512 2618437157  False   stable-diffusion    ed55d762-2b05-400a-9a38-fe43febbc8f4    False
39  ab5ef0cb-6a88-4f5a-88d7-452e42526c06    https://lexica.art?q=ab5ef0cb-6a88-4f5a-88d7-452e42526c06   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/ab5ef0cb-6a88-4f5a-88d7-452e42526c06  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/ab5ef0cb-6a88-4f5a-88d7-452e42526c06  rotten tentacles coming out of a rotten apple inside a glass jar on a kitchen table hyperrealistic photography detailed 1536    1536    2594159325  True    stable-diffusion    fb0a6c61-d95c-4bd0-a340-9cc32a554b1e    False
40  b2148da3-739f-4c6c-b42d-156e12749f16    https://lexica.art?q=b2148da3-739f-4c6c-b42d-156e12749f16   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/b2148da3-739f-4c6c-b42d-156e12749f16  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/b2148da3-739f-4c6c-b42d-156e12749f16  square apple    512 512 1337697659  False   stable-diffusion    db6d85d8-6ed5-4367-8075-0fcba7e0971c    False
41  c37b889f-5bef-4365-9d1d-452852356286    https://lexica.art?q=c37b889f-5bef-4365-9d1d-452852356286   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/c37b889f-5bef-4365-9d1d-452852356286  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/c37b889f-5bef-4365-9d1d-452852356286  a girl with a red cloak holding a basket full of apples, by Jordan Grimmer and greg rutkowski, crisp lines and color,   512 512 3701828881  False   stable-diffusion    418452df-cdad-434d-9d4d-56a82eac104b    False
42  d42096de-94e2-4745-8c72-5df8a25e09c6    https://lexica.art?q=d42096de-94e2-4745-8c72-5df8a25e09c6   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/d42096de-94e2-4745-8c72-5df8a25e09c6  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/d42096de-94e2-4745-8c72-5df8a25e09c6  an illustration of an apple in american dad style   512 512 1620054386  False   stable-diffusion    edde6394-9bd6-44a4-8519-5b68ad27f567    False
43  d81ccfea-4859-4ac3-ba96-439b2c8b0d2b    https://lexica.art?q=d81ccfea-4859-4ac3-ba96-439b2c8b0d2b   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/d81ccfea-4859-4ac3-ba96-439b2c8b0d2b  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/d81ccfea-4859-4ac3-ba96-439b2c8b0d2b  an apple by René Magritte   2304    1536    404303797   True    stable-diffusion    dd807e9f-3c89-40fc-ad8b-7be6f77f68d2    False
44  dc3ec4e5-1d16-4615-adde-54152bfe35fd    https://lexica.art?q=dc3ec4e5-1d16-4615-adde-54152bfe35fd   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/dc3ec4e5-1d16-4615-adde-54152bfe35fd  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/dc3ec4e5-1d16-4615-adde-54152bfe35fd  a photo of an apple 512 512 2529659975  False   stable-diffusion    e6b15326-39ce-4ee9-b8c9-152393a13c54    False
45  e05d6d83-385b-4031-9beb-b0a156b68f4d    https://lexica.art?q=e05d6d83-385b-4031-9beb-b0a156b68f4d   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/e05d6d83-385b-4031-9beb-b0a156b68f4d  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/e05d6d83-385b-4031-9beb-b0a156b68f4d  bonsai apple! tree but minimalistic concept art by frank stella gilleard james whalen tom, colorful, soft light, trending on artstation, minimalism 512 512 2286171972  False   stable-diffusion    610520a3-7123-4cd0-b8b6-428f12cfa952    False
46  e587bb8f-4fc5-4854-88e3-b87b6c8d3bd2    https://lexica.art?q=e587bb8f-4fc5-4854-88e3-b87b6c8d3bd2   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/e587bb8f-4fc5-4854-88e3-b87b6c8d3bd2  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/e587bb8f-4fc5-4854-88e3-b87b6c8d3bd2  impressionist oil painting of a hybrid kangaroo apple   1536    1536    2667333849  True    stable-diffusion    853a71a5-c4b6-43dd-baa4-e50ab8401130    False
47  ec123cde-635d-437c-bcc8-b8f4a79f9390    https://lexica.art?q=ec123cde-635d-437c-bcc8-b8f4a79f9390   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/ec123cde-635d-437c-bcc8-b8f4a79f9390  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/ec123cde-635d-437c-bcc8-b8f4a79f9390  apple cores in different art styles 512 512 616795706   False   stable-diffusion    44f9707d-f68e-4ead-a1d1-0e71dc239011    False
48  efa8bdc0-f8ea-481f-886a-4609a635b38c    https://lexica.art?q=efa8bdc0-f8ea-481f-886a-4609a635b38c   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/efa8bdc0-f8ea-481f-886a-4609a635b38c  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/efa8bdc0-f8ea-481f-886a-4609a635b38c  painting portrait of a beautiful girl with an apple in her hand, intricate, elegant, digital painting, smooth, sharp focus, shiny gold, realistic gold, realistic metal, by William-Adolphe Bouguereau and Gustav Klimt,    576 1024    68677281    False   stable-diffusion    3063bb65-a859-420f-8ebe-efd0a83e7937    False
49  fe942971-1896-4389-8134-022618bb876a    https://lexica.art?q=fe942971-1896-4389-8134-022618bb876a   https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/md/fe942971-1896-4389-8134-022618bb876a  https://lexica-serve-encoded-images.sharif.workers.dev/sm/fe942971-1896-4389-8134-022618bb876a  highly detailed apple   512 512 2472327392  False   stable-diffusion    2f159d63-ea1e-4648-afc7-5278c8ce16f7    False
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Barry the Platipus. The thing is I also found that api example before posing this question. I'm actually looking for the random images that show up when you open this [link](https://lexica.art/).